# Eliminating deviants while computing score

Tags: algorithm

I have a relatively simple algorithmic problem where I recommend questions for users

1. I have a set of questions with answers (like, comments for each
   answer)
2. I want to score how engaging each question is.

Current implementation:

```
(total comments + likes for all answers for a question) / sqrt (number of answers)
```

Problems:

1. Sometimes, one answer that has a tonne of activity skews the score for the question, even if the other 20 answers generate very little interest
2. Some reduction should be applied for questions with very few answers.

Would appreciate any suggestions on these 2 problems can be negated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we want to avoid letting one sample from being too powerful, the standard way to do it is by one of these:

1. use `log(N)` instead of `N`, making the effect of each observation less powerful<sup>1</sup>
2. leave the "strange" observations out: Take only the middle X%, and use them, for example: take only observations that has 1/4 - 3/4 likes, from the max of this question, and leave the skewing examples out.

For the second issue - one thing I can think of is giving a varainting factor: instead using `sqrt(number of answers)` - you can try `(number_of_answers)^(log(number_of_answers+1)/log(max_answers+1))` where `max_answers` is the maximal number of answer per question in your data set.

It will result in boosting up questions with few answers, which I think is what you are after.

---

**(1)**: We usually take `log(N+1)` - so it will be defined for `N==0` as well.